Stress Strain Graph: Despite crossing breaking point stress before UTS, why doesn't the material break?


Why does the material not break despite crossing the breaking stress beforehand [Red Point]

Increasing tensile stress, thins out the material => Cross Sectional Area decreases, then how does Stress decrease after UTS? Isn't Stress = $\frac{F}{A}$, A decreases, so Stress must be larger no? Is force constant or not? If not could you expand on why stress decreases?



The key to understanding is that the stress-strain plot is at the macro, black-box level and does not involve detailed descriptions of what is happening to the sample. The strain is increased by, e.g., a screw actuator and the resulting stress is a measure of the force applied across the sample. The machine has no idea of what any cross sectional area is or if it is changing or not. The conditions of the sample at final fracture are not the same as at the red dot.

@JonCuster
"The machine has no idea of what any cross sectional area is or if it is changing or not": Then how is the graph being produced/ how is the stress or strain being calculated?
"Conditions of the sample at final fracture are not the same as at the red dot.": What is the key difference in condition?

The strain is controlled by the machine. The "stress" is the force measured by a load cell divided by the original, unstrained cross section of the sample. The difference in the condition is in the notes above the graph - strain hardening and then necking (area reduction of part of the sample).

@JonCuster Correct me if I am wrong. From what I am understanding is that the strain is measured by the machine, stress does increase, but the difference in rate of stress and rate of strain is what causes the curve to bend downwards, right? Thanks for the end part.

Strain is controlled (set) by the machine - it keeps turning the lead screw to make the sample elongate. Force is measured by the machine (load cell) and converted to stress by assuming the original cross sectional area. When necking starts, a locally-reduced cross sectional area, the force required to keep straining goes down. Again, the "Stress" on the graph is derived from the measured force and the assumed constant initial cross section. It is NOT an actual stress measurement.

Wait, Strain is kept fixed? Do you mean due to necking, force required is less, but why is force varying like that? Why isn't it continuously kept increasing? @JonCuster

Strain is the control variable - you tell the machine to increase the length of the sample at a given rate and it will make it so. Once necking starts the local cross section area drops, so the local stress increases. A constant applied force causes continued necking further decreasing the cross section so the local applied stress can increase. Ultimately you need less applied force across the sample to have a higher local stress at the neck until it pulls apart and fails.

@JonCuster On some research, I have found that my graph is the Engineering Stress Strain graph. Your explanation resembles one for the true Stress Strain graph, my question now is why for engineering curve the stress decreases after UTS. [Hope I aint being annoying]

The 'engineering' curve is what the Instron testing machine supplies, i.e. that kind of graph. True stress-strain requires more detailed knowledge of the actual state of the sample, including actual cross sectional area(s).

Consider to spell out acronyms.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248278/2451
